# How to create a new string from a range in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

What would be the most concise and/or idiomatic way to create a `std::string` from a transformed view (of another string)?

The best I could come up is to use `std::ranges::copy` with the view and inserter as arguments, and even that is only accepted by gcc (10.2 & trunk) but not clang 11.x.

For most `ranges` algorithms, I thought the intent was that the `operator|` can be used whenever the first argument to a function is a range, so I wonder why the 2nd and IMHO cleaner variant doesn't compile (the error message is that no matching `copy` was found), and is the intent to maybe eventually have it compile, or what?

I tried with both gcc 10.2 and gcc (11) trunk. Clang doesn't compile the first form either :(

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string original = "foo";
    std::string upper;

    // This compiles on gcc 10.2/11-trunk only
    std::ranges::copy(
        original 
            | std::ranges::views::transform([](char c){return std::toupper(c);}),
        std::back_inserter(upper)
    ); 

    // The below doesn't compile period
    original
        | std::ranges::views::transform([](char c){return std::toupper(c);})
        | std::ranges::copy(std::back_inserter(upper));
}
```

Comment: [This is nice article](https://timur.audio/how-to-make-a-container-from-a-c20-range).

Comment: @MarekR Thanks. But that doesn't explain why the first version doesn't work in clang, unless clang or its library has a bug...

Comment: clang is quite behind to gcc with range support.

Answer (score 7):

> For most ranges algorithms, I thought the intent was that the `operator|` can be used whenever the first argument to a function is a range

This isn't quite right. `operator|` is only provided for those algorithms for which the first argument is a range *and* the result is a range.

`transform`, `filter`, `take`, etc., are all algorithms that take a range and return a range. More specifically, they take a `viewable_range` and return a `view`.

But for all the other algorithms - `max`, `find_if`, `any_of`, etc. - that don't return a range, there is no `|` alternative to them. So this:

```cpp
    original
        | std::ranges::views::transform([](char c){return std::toupper(c);})
        | std::ranges::copy(std::back_inserter(upper));
```

isn't even intended to work, because `copy` is not one of the algorithms that returns a `view`, so it doesn't get `|` support. One of the motivations of the pipeline-rewrite operator proposal ([P2011](https://wg21.link/p2011)) is to be able to use such functionality (without the massive library machinery necessary to make it work).

---

On the other hand, this:

```cpp
    std::ranges::copy(
        original 
            | std::ranges::views::transform([](char c){return std::toupper(c);}),
        std::back_inserter(upper)
    );
```

is perfectly valid code that is intended to work. This is caused by clang checking some concepts too eagerly (see [bug 47509](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47509)). I think there's another bug report too, just can't find it at the moment.

---

Eventually the `ranges::to` from range-v3 will be adopted, so the intended idiomatic construction would be:

```cpp
    std::string upper = 
        original 
            | std::ranges::views::transform([](char c){return std::toupper(c);}),
            | std::ranges::to<std::string>();
```

Which, until then, you can use range-v3 for `to`.

Comment: `ranges::to` seems like the bees knees - thank you!

Comment: Why `ranges::copy` + `views::transform` instead of just `std::ranges::transform(original, std::back_inserter(upper), [](unsigned char c){ return std::toupper(c); })`?

Comment: @metalfox Because it won't compile otherwise. There's no way to construct `std::string` directly from a lazy range view. `std::copy` performs this, and with ranges-v3, `to` does the trick.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica It does compile with GCC 11: https://wandbox.org/permlink/jn00jE2Vu7UscMTJ . I believe that you misread my comment.